# Bias in Quantile Regression

Tags: bias, assumptions, quantile-regression

What are the assumption for the quantile regression estimator to be unbiased? I looked up [Koenker 2005](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantile-regression/C18AE7BCF3EC43C16937390D44A328B1) but only found a theorem on consistency.

Comment: Might it be the quantile estimator is *always* biased? Just speculating.

Comment: I think so too. However, I am having trouble actually finding such a statement.